# HTML jQuery select option value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to use the jQuery ajax function upon a HTML option value form choice.

Here is my form in HTML:

```
<form action="#">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label for="gender">Gender</label></td>

                        <select id="gender">
                        <option value="male" selected="selected">Male</option>
                        <option value="female">Female</option>

                        </select> <br />
                        <input>
                        </td>
                        <input type="button" value="SUBMIT" id="getGender"/>

                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
```

And this is my Javascript:

```
$('#getGender').click(function(){

      if($('#gender').val() == 'male'){

          // do stuff

      }else if ($('#gender').val() == 'female'){

          // do stuff

      }

});
```

But It does not answer to the if/else it statement. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: When is `$('#getGender')` called? Does the code get into the click method? Any errors in the console? We need more details to help you out.

Comment: wrap your code in ready() function . make sure you have added jquery lib

Comment: Why did you mention ajax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the working one on jsfiddle

```
https://jsfiddle.net/e892gnhb/
```

Code

```
$('#getGender').click(function(){

      if($('#gender option:selected').text() == 'Male'){

          alert('male');

      }else if($('#gender option:selected').text() == 'Female'){

          alert('female');

      }

});
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/qsdn9qxa/. This is one using jquery val() method.
Please tick as correct answer if this answer helped you.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that for me zer0fl4g, I did not know. I just did.

Answer (score 1):

You're not actually grabbing the selected option.. here's how you would get it:

```
$("#gender option:selected" ).val()
```

**[edit]**
As, mentioned by Nishit Maheta in the comment, you can also just do:

```
$('#gender').val()
```

And, rather than the `click` event, you want to bind to the `change` event of your `#gender` select element:

```
$('#gender').change(function(){
    if($(this).val() === "male"){
        console.log("male")
        // male!
    } else if($(this).val() === "female"){
        console.log("female");
        // female!
    }
});
```

```js
$('#gender').change(function(){
    if($(this).val() === "male"){
        console.log("male")
        // male!
    } else if($(this).val() === "female"){
        console.log("female");
        // female!
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="gender">
    <option value="male" selected="selected">Male</option>
    <option value="female">Female</option>
</select>
```

Comment: `$('#gender').val()` give same result

Answer (score 1):

> try this . If you are asking this , then please check my demo .

```
DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/jwxLzf6x/
```